# Program freezes, multithread? Locksupport.park method

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to extract establishments data from GooglePlaces API. It used to work initially, but after making a specific method for extracting the places (instead of in the main method), the program crushes. When debbuged it, it gets stuck in a java method called park (under LockSupport class from java). Reading about it, it says that this happens when there is more than 1 thread and there are sync problems. I'm very new at this and I don't know how to solve this in my code. In my mind, there is only 1 thread in this code, but I'm pretty sure I'm wrong. Please help. It crashes in a "for" commented below. Thanks so much!

```
package laundry;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import se.walkercrou.places.GooglePlaces;
import se.walkercrou.places.Param;
import se.walkercrou.places.Place;
import java.io.FileWriter; //add to import list
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.microedition.location.Coordinates;
import se.walkercrou.places.exception.GooglePlacesException;
import se.walkercrou.places.exception.RequestDeniedException;


public class Laundry {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<Place> detailedPlaces = new ArrayList<>();
    List<double[]> circlesPoint = new ArrayList<>();
    double radio = 10;
    Coordinates startingPoint = new Coordinates     (-38.182476,144.552079,0);//geelong south west corner of the grid
    Coordinates finalPoint   = new Coordinates(-37.574381,145.415879,0); //north east of melbourne
    GooglePlaces cliente = new GooglePlaces("keyof googlplaces");
    MyResult result1=exploreGrid(startingPoint,finalPoint, radio, detailedPlaces, circlesPoint,cliente); 
    writeResultsCircles(result1.getPoints(),"c:\\outputCircles.txt" );
    writeResultsPlaces(result1.getPlaces(), "c:\\outputPlaces.txt");
}   

private static MyResult exploreGrid(Coordinates SWpoint,Coordinates NEpoint,double rad, List<Place> lugares, List<double[]> points,GooglePlaces client){
    int iterationRow=0;
    Coordinates workingPoint = new Coordinates(SWpoint.getLatitude(),SWpoint.getLongitude(),(float) 0.0);
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
    while (workingPoint.getLatitude()<NEpoint.getLatitude()){
        while (workingPoint.getLongitude()<NEpoint.getLongitude()){
            try {
                places = client.getNearbyPlaces(workingPoint.getLatitude(), workingPoint.getLongitude(), rad*1000,GooglePlaces.MAXIMUM_RESULTS ,Param.name("types").value("laundry"));
                if (places.size()==60){//si se llega al tope de resultados de getNearbyPlaces
                    iterationRow=1;
                }
                for (Place place : places) {
                     lugares.add(place.getDetails());//here is where it crashes
                }
            }catch (GooglePlacesException ex) {   
                System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            }

            double[] prePoint = {workingPoint.getLatitude(),workingPoint.getLongitude(),rad};
            points.add(prePoint);
            workingPoint.setLongitude(workingPoint.getLongitude()+rad*sqrt(3)*0.01134787);
        }
        iterationRow++;
        if (isEven(iterationRow)){
            workingPoint.setLongitude(SWpoint.getLongitude()); 
        } else {
            workingPoint.setLongitude(SWpoint.getLongitude()+rad*sqrt(3)*0.01134787/2); 
        }

        workingPoint.setLatitude(workingPoint.getLatitude()+rad*3/2*0.00899416);
    }
    return new MyResult(lugares,points);
}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't really crash though, does it? It just stops, because it's waiting for `place.getDetails();` to return. If you have the sources, you can check what's happening inside the `getDetails()` method. Most likely some network action, so it's no surprise if it blocks for a while. It should return a value or timeout after a while.

Comment: It doesn't crash, it stops running. Debugging when it stops working, it gets stuck in "park"method, under Class Lock Support in the line:         UNSAFE.park(false, 0L);

Comment: It's waiting. How long have you waited to see if it returns?

Comment: Like 10 minutes, but nothing. Not even a time out output.. Trying to debug even deeper, found that the sentence that leave the program waiting is the following (in another class of the library of google places that I downloaded)...
    `public String get(String uri) throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
            return readString(client.execute(get)); //in this sentence
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }`

Comment: It's trying to perform a HTTP GET request, apparently without a timeout. I suggest you observe the network traffic to see what's happening.

Comment: Apparently the HttpGet works, because it stops working in the `client.execute(get)` sentence. I tried to go to the definition of that execute method, but the code seems blocked (without a javadoc). The weirdest thing is that when I run the initial code all in the main, I didn't have any problem. Actually when I run this code (the faulty one). The program assing the first Place to the lugares variable. The problem appears with the second place....I'm too rockie for this

Comment: It's executing the request and blocking as it waits for the value to return. If you capture the network traffic, you can see if it has trouble connecting or reading (or processing the results, although that would be a bug in the library).

Comment: Appreciate your thoughts @Kayaman. I'll try

Comment: Opened the IDE Log, and the last message (when the program stops) says: "Source path "sun\misc\Unsafe.java" was not found". What would this mean? Is it possible that the Java libraries are not updated? I just downloaded JDK 1.8.

Comment: It just means that it can't show you the source code of the `Unsafe` class, which implements a lot of the low level methods, such as waiting on monitors and such (e.g. `Unsafe.park()`). I keep telling you to monitor the network traffic. Are you going to do it? Whip up Wireshark and see if the request gets even sent.